# Java iterate through a set of classes

Tags: java, reflection

I have the following code:

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections("com.mypackage.cmds");
Set<Class<? extends Command>> commandClasses = reflections.getSubTypesOf(Command.class);
```

What it does is to store in a Set all classes descendant from Command class that are within the package com.mypackage.cmds.

Now what I want to do is to iterate or traverse through that returned set so each of those classes are loaded calling Class.fromName method. How can I achieve this?

Thanks a lot in advance,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do it with a standard [for-each](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/language/foreach.html) loop:

```
for (Class clazz: commandClasses) {
    // operate on clazz
}
```

This works for any Collection that implements the [`Iterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) interface.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this :

```
Iterator i = commandClasses.iterator();
        while (i.hasNext()) {
            i.next(); //will return next object     
        }
```